# 403 when performing PUT request

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am very new to apache configurations and am trying to learn more. I am getting a `403 - Forbidden` when making a `PUT` request, however a `GET` to the same URL works fine.

Is there something I need to enable to allow `PUT` requests?

I am using Apache and PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with Apache 2.4.x, a faulty or missing "Require" directive could the cause of the 403.

In the  `<Directory>` block of your virtualhost config, or your `.htaccess` file add the following line:

```
Require all granted
```

For details on the "Require" syntax see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require