# Novice REST server setup

Tags: javascript, apache, rest

I've just begun trying to write a REST server to understand how it works. I have XAMPP for my stack, am using .htaccess to direct requests properly, and the server responds to GET requests just fine. But Apache returns a 403 error when I try to make a PUT request to the same URI.

I'm getting no Apache errors, and my server code doesn't seem to be getting accessed when I checked that. The Apache log simply shows the 403 (and verifies I used the same URI). Can anybody suggest how I can track this down further? I'd like to understand the process before trying to switch to a library.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
Require all granted
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule endpoint/(.*)$ endpoint/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

---

edit: I was hoping for hints about how to track down this problem. It finally succumbed to 'poke everywhere until I stumble upon the answer'. It turns out httpd-userdir was configured to block PUT requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 when performing PUT request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794642/403-when-performing-put-request)

Comment: Sorry, no. Putting that directive in either the .htaccess or the httpd.conf results in no change: 403 Access Forbidden.